# Demanding references for answers to questions that are not reference requests

Tags: discussion, policies, answers, asking-questions

I propose that for questions that are not tagged with the [reference-request](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag (i.e., questions that are not of the form "What are some good references for X?" or similar), answers are still encouraged to provide references if possible, but the asker doesn't make demands such as "make sure your answer has a lot of references too".

For all questions here, it is implied that the best answers will be the ones that are thorough (including good references, if necessary), but we don't need to express this in the form of a demand in every single question on the site. Furthermore, in many cases, references are not really necessary (e.g. I did not provide any references for the step-by-step derivation that I gave in [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10947/5)) and in such cases, the explicit demand for references by the asker, can discourage people who would otherwise be capable of writing good answers.